# I need the combinatorial proof for the following identity

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

$$
\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{n}{r}}{r+1}=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}
$$

I know how to write combinatorial proof when the radicals are being added or multiplied. I want to know how to do the same in the case of division of radicals.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hint: $$(n+1)\binom nr=(r+1)\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$

Comment: It is hard to prove things combinatorially when the terms might not be integers. But multiplying both sides by $n+1$ you can show the terms are integers.

Comment: At heart you want a combinatorial proof of $\frac{n+1}{r+1}\binom nr=\binom{n+1}{r+1}.$

Comment: What do you mean by "radicals" here?

Comment: This might interest you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658676/ But read also [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Other possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87249/386889

Answer (score 1):

We will use the lemma:

$$(n+1)\binom nr=(r+1)\binom{n+1}{r+1}\tag1$$

This can be proved combinatorially counting in two ways the number of committees of $r+1$ people from $n+1$ people, with one committee member selected as chairperson.

The left side of $(1)$ corresponds to choosing the chair first, and then choosing the $r$ other members, while the right side chooses the $r+1$ members and then selects the chair from those $r+1.$

From $(1),$ you get:

$$\frac{n+1}{r+1}\binom nr=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$

And thus $$(n+1)\sum_{r=0}^n\frac1{r+1}\binom nr=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom {n+1}{r+1}\tag2$$

But the right side of $(2)$ counts the non-empty subsets of a set of size $n+1,$ which is $2^{n+1}-1.$

Then we divide by $n+1.$

It is not really possible to prove directly the original formula combinatorially because the values are not always integers. You have to find a common denominator to turn it into an integer equation, but luckily, here, one common denominator is $n+1.$

Comment: You can avoid rearrangement by using expectation (i.e probability). See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a purely combinatorial argument without rearrangement.

Suppose you draw a permutation $\pi$ uniformly at random from $[n+1]=\{1, 2, \ldots, n+1\}$. You are interested in the expected number $\mu$ of subsets of $S\subseteq [n]$ such that $n+1$ is after all the elements of $S$ in the permutation $\pi$.

For example, if $n=3$, and the permutation drawn is $\pi=2143$, then the subsets are $\{2\}, \{1\}, \{2,1\}, \{\}$ for a total of $4$.

How do we compute $\mu$? One way is to use Linearity of expectation on the size of the subsets $S$:

$$\mu = \sum_{r=0}^{n} \sum_{S\subseteq [n], |S|=r} \Pr[n+1 \text{ is after }S \text{ in }\pi] = \sum_{r=0}^{n} \sum_{S\subseteq[n], |S|=r}\frac{1}{r+1}$$
This is because if we focus on the $r$ elements of $S$ and $n+1$, the probability the random permutation has $n+1$ after $S$ is $1/(r+1)$. But this summation simplifies to

$$\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{{n \choose r}}{r+1}$$

Now we calculate $\mu$ a different way. Consider the location of $n+1$ in $\pi$. It lands in location $\ell, 1\leq \ell \leq n+1$ with probability $1/(n+1)$. If it falls in location $\ell$, then only the $2^{\ell-1}$ subsets generated by the elements before $\ell$ count in the expectation. So again, the expectation is

$$\mu = \sum_{\ell=1}^{n+1}2^{\ell-1}\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$$

Answer (score -1):

**Set Up**

My class has $n+1$ students including myself. During the break, we do the following fun activity:

- A non-empty subset of students are selected
- At random, one of the selected students is slapped

The activity is repeated, each with a different non-empty subset and it's stopped only when there is no more distinct non-empty subset left. What is the expected value of slaps I get?

**Left Hand Side**

The number of subsets with $r+1$ people including myself is $\binom{n}{r}$ and in this group my chance of getting slapped is $\frac{1}{r+1}$. Therefore the expected number of slaps I get is given by the left hand side:

$$
\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{1}{r+1}\binom{n}{r}
$$

**Right Hand Side**

There are a total of $2^{n+1}-1$ non-empty subsets and each students must have the same expected number of slaps. Therefore my (and others') expected number of slaps is given by the right hand side:

$$
\frac{1}{n+1}\left(2^{n+1}-1\right)
$$

**Conclusion**

Since LHS and RHS calculate the same thing, they must be equal i.e.

$$
\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{1}{r+1}\binom{n}{r}
=
\frac{1}{n+1}\left(2^{n+1}-1\right)
$$

**Remarks**

When I encounter fractions and want to use combinatorial proof, the first thing that comes to my mind is probability or expected value.

Answer (score -2):

Hint 1: the LHS is $$\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} \int_0^1 x^r\mathrm d x = \int_0^1(1+x)^n\mathrm dx$$

---

Hint 2: If you want a pure combinatorial proof. How many non empty subsets there in a set of cardinality $n+1$?

- $\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n+1}{r+1}$
- $2^{n+1} -1$

Now rearrange terms and you will find your identity

Comment: A combinatorial proof is a proof that counts the cardinality of a set two different ways such that the LHS and RHS represent the cardinality of that set. Your proof is not combinatorial since it requires rearrangement.

Comment: I don't agree with your definition. You can rearrange after using a combinatorial argument and it still a combinatorial proof.

Comment: Your definition makes no sense. If you can rearrange, then you can rearrange to a trivial expression which is trivially true. The main idea behind combinatorial proofs is to find clever sets/events to count the LHS and RHS as given!

Comment: It makes perfectly sense to me.

Comment: This is not what is meant by a combinatorial proof, traditionally. You can use words as you want, but if you choose to use them in ways others don't use them, you are going to be perceived as wrong a lot.